# How to use Smack with android

Tags: android, connection, xmpp, smack

I have following code which uses smack 4.1.0 for connection with xmpp server im.koderoot.net, this host/service is working for java application for which I have used  smack3.1.0 and smacx3.1.0 but in java when I am using the jars it throws the following exception

```
09-01 18:29:18.921: E/SMACK EXCEPTION(1577): org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: im.koderoot.net:5222 Exception: null
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zzxmpp;


import java.io.IOException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private XMPPTCPConnection mConnection;
    private Button connect;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        connect.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.XMPPTCPConnectionConfigurationBuilder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
            builder.setServiceName("im.koderoot.net");
            builder.setPort(5222);
            builder.setResource("SmackAndroidTestClient");
            builder.setUsernameAndPassword("xxxx", "xxxx");
            builder.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);


            mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(builder.build());
            //Set ConnectionListener here to catch initial connect();
          //  mConnection.addConnectionListener(this);

            try {
                mConnection.connect();
                mConnection.login();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Smack Exception"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO Exception"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "XMPP Exception"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }


}
```

I have following .jar files in project

smack-android-4.1.0-alpha6.jar

smack-tcp-4.1.0-alpha6.jar

minidns-0.1.1.jar

smack-sasl-provided-4.1.0-alpha6.jar

smack-core-4.1.0-alpha6.jar

smack-resolver-minidns-4.1.0-alpha6.jar

jxmpp-util-cache-0.4.0-alpha2.jar

jxmpp-core-0.4.0.jar

**I found a following working solution myself**

Replace all the jar files by asmack-2010.05.07.jar and asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11.jar

And Change the code to following

```
package com.demo.xmppchat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class XMPPChatDemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String HOST = "im.koderoot.net";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    //public static final String SERVICE = "slogin.oscar.aol.com";

    public static final String USERNAME = "XXXXXXX";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "XXXXXX";

    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private ListView listview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
        textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
        listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        setListAdapter();

        // Set a listener to send a chat text message
        Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String to = recipient.getText().toString();
                String text = textMessage.getText().toString();

                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Sending text " + text + " to " + to);
                Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);              
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                    messages.add(text);
                    setListAdapter();
                }
            }
        });

        connect();
    }

    /**
     * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is established with the XMPP
     * server
     * 
     * @param connection
     */
    public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        if (connection != null) {
            // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    Message message = (Message) packet;
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                                .getFrom());
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved " + message.getBody()
                                + " from " + fromName );
                        messages.add(fromName + ":");
                        messages.add(message.getBody());
                        // Add the incoming message to the list view
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                setListAdapter();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        }
    }

    private void setListAdapter() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, messages);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    public void connect() {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                        HOST, PORT);//, SERVICE);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                            + connection.getHost());
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                try {
                    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                    // Set the status to available
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    setConnection(connection);

                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "--------------------------------------");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "User: " + entry.getUser());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Name: " + entry.getName());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Type: " + entry.getType());
                        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                                .getUser());


                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                                + entryPresence.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                                + entryPresence.getType());
                        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                                + entryPresence);

                    }
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                            + USERNAME);
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ConnectionException is thrown when host cannot be reached.

Check following things may help you.

1. forget to add permission at the manifest file (I do this a lot of time)

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

2. check if it can ping im.koderoot.net from your Android device
3. add e.printStackTrace(); at exception catch will give more hints

I have just registered at im.koderoot.net and use smack4.1.3 to connect without problem.

One more thing is that your code will cause ANR (Application Not Responding) in long run, but it is another topic.

Comment: I already have internet permissions in manifest file also i changed the smack version from 4.1.0 to 4.1.3 but still its not working and throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration exaception

Comment: I made changes to the program to make it wok. I have used customized asmack (asmack-2010.05.07.jar and asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11.jar ) and change the code to updated code in question